# Passing value through JQuery options object

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm having a problem understanding how callback functions work.

I'm using JCrop to crop many images on a page. JCrop is written under the impression that there may only be 1 image that needs to be cropped:

> jQuery(function() 
>             {
>
> ```
>               CropMe.Jcrop //CropMe is the class holding the image
>               ({
>                   aspectRatio: 1,
>                   onSelect: updateCoords
>               });
>           }
>       });
> ```

When it updates the coordinates via "onSelect" it outputs the coords in the function "updateCoords
" so that they can be read in a form later on submit:

> function updateCoords(c)
>   {
>
> $('.x').val(c.x);
>
> $('.y').val(c.y);
>
> $('.w').val(c.w);
>
> $('.h').val(c.h);
>   }

the problem is, is that I have MANY Jcrops instantiated under a class, not a specific id. Therefore, when updateCoords is called, it doesn't know which x,y,w,h values to update.

How would I pass an argument(specifically CropMe) through the option object so that i can change the 4 relevant values

relevant code:[jquery.jcrop,js](http://pastebin.com/qeuRNX5A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          CropMe.Jcrop //CropMe is the class holding the image
          ({
              aspectRatio: 1,
              onSelect: function(c) { updateCoords(c, CropMe); }
          });
```

Then `updateCoords` would look something like:

```
function updateCoords(c, cropMeObject) {
  // cropMeObject is the CropMe object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `this` keyword to refer to the CropMe object using a closure should work:

```
CropMe.Jcrop //CropMe is the class holding the image
  ({
      aspectRatio: 1,
      onSelect:    (function(c) { return updateCoords(c); })(c,this);
  });
```

now in function updateCoords you can refer to `this`.